# Combining data-toggle="tab" and data-toggle="dropdown" in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a dropdown tab with the following behavior:

- clicking on the tab's text doesn't trigger the dropdown menu, but navigates to the given link (data-toggle="tab")
- clicking on the caret next to the tab's text triggers the dropdown (data-toggle="dropdown")

So if I click on "Menu 1", the tab content should change, but the dropdown menu shouldn't be visible. If I click on the caret next to "Menu 1", the tab content shouldn't change, and the dropdown menu should be shown instead.

Is it somehow possible to solve this in bootstrap?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's totally do-able using bootstrap, but why separate the tab function and view by the tab name & caret icon? It makes more logically sense for users to 1) click on dropdown tab, 2) select subsections, 3) display the tab view for that subsection. Anyways you should take a read of bootstrap's tab section here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Comment: I agree that it would make more sense the way you described it, but this is the current requirement :) I had a look at the link you pointed me to, but I still don't see how this separation (not triggering the dropdonw when clicking on the tab text) is possible.